# How to compare [String]? and String in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, compare

When I try to compare `[String]?` and `String` I get the error:

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String]?' and 'String'

Could anyone tell me how to compare them?

Comment: You'll have to be more clear on how you want to compare a collection of `String` to a single `String`. Do you want to know if any item in the collection is not equal to the single item?

Comment: Just give us an example of what you are trying to do and show the code that gave you this error.

Comment: Thanks for all you guys effort. Im new in Swift and just got confuse with the "Question Mark". And not realised the one Im comparing actually is an array. Finally understand just need to do like `array![0]=="anystring"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare a string with an optional array of strings, they have two different types: The equality operator `==`, as defined in the standard library, can't compare a string to an optional array of strings.

**If** you want to check if an optional array contains a string, then use the following:

```
let array: [String]? = ["hello", "world", "✋"]
let result = array?.contains("hello")
```

`result` would be an optional boolean that you may unwrap later.

Answer (score 0):

var array = ["First", "Second"]
    let loneString = "Second"

```
for k in 0..<array.count {

    if array[k] != loneString {

        print("they are not same") 

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile (you can't unwrap a string that isn't optional) + `array` is optional in the question